# Pass array to function - PG and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, pg

Using `pg` in my NodeJS application I would like to be able to pass an array to a function so that I can use the `IN` statement as part of my query

Example

```
async function myMethod(array) {
  // array looks like [ '83', '82', '54', '55', '79' ] for example
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE id IN($1)", [array]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  return response.rows;
}
```

I get an error

```
{ error: invalid input syntax for integer: "{"83","82","54","55","79"}"
```

How do I go about structuring my query here please?

Comment: Have you tried converting the array to a string? Querys should get string objects to prepare the statement.

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet is to just go with:

```
pool.query("SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE id IN($1:list)", [array]);
// [1,2,3]→"SELECT * FROM fixtures WHERE id IN(1,2,3)"
```

When a variable ends with `:list`, it is formatted as a list of Comma-Separated Values, with each value formatted according to its JavaScript type.

The reason you need that is that arrays are formatted to PostgreSQL arrays by default, which is denoted as you've seen with curly braces.

---

Note: This was added to `pg` (or rather, `pg-promise`), in v7.5.1. If you're using an earlier version, use `$1:csv` instead.

---

*Source*: [pg-promise#csv-filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter)

Comment: Thank you for help, I take it i should not be getting `error: syntax error at or near ":" `and i have `pg` installed, do i need to add `pg-promise` aswell for this to work ?

Comment: @Richlewis `pg` is dated relative to `pg-promise`, and I see you're using promises anyway (`await` in your code), so yeah, instead of promisifyng `pg`, just switch over to `pg-promise`. After `npm i` just do `const pg = require('pg-promise')` and no changes in your app follow.